# Access nested properties with dynamic lambda using Linq.Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

Let's assume that I have two classes:

```
class person
{
    int ID
    string name
    Address address
}
class address
{
    int ID
    string street
    string country
}
```

These classes are more or less given, they are mapped via nHibernate to be honest :)

In a grid ([datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net) as base) I would like to have a type-independent sorting.

Therefore I created a lambda expression:

```
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), typeof(T).Name);
  var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
                              (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, "Property to sort"), typeof(object)), param);
```

If I pass Person as Type T and replace the "Property to sort" with "name" it works fine (creates a correct lambda). If the Property to sort is "address.street" it won't work, throw me the following error:

```
Property 'address.street' is not defined for type 'person'
```

I see only one solution so far, but not clear enough... I would try to split the string which contains the Property-Name (split by .)

Can anyone give a better solution? I need to add the sortExpression to an IQueryable object `query.OrderBy(sortExpression)`.

Not sure if my title is clear, please go ahead and correct it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

What is not clear?

You have to split it and then use:

```
Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param, "address"), "street")
```

Comment: uhm and how would you do that if maybe there comes something like
`person.company.address.street` ? I just don't know how to "nest" it.. or if there are some other ways, like Craig posted...

Comment: Expression.Property(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param, "person"), "company"),"address"),"street")

Simple loop will work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more generic version of LukLed's answer:

```
    protected MemberExpression NestedExpressionProperty(Expression expression, string propertyName)
    {
        string[] parts = propertyName.Split('.');
        int partsL = parts.Length;

        return (partsL > 1) 
            ? 
            Expression.Property( 
                NestedExpressionProperty(
                    expression, 
                    parts.Take(partsL - 1)
                        .Aggregate((a, i) => a + "." + i)
                ), 
                parts[partsL - 1]) 
            :
            Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(this.type, "val");
var firstProp = NestedExpressionProperty(paramExpression,"address.street");
```

Comment: This is an excellent and reusable method to solve this problem.  Thank-you.

Comment: Excellent answer +1. You could do this in one liner: `return propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate(expression, (body, member) => Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member));`.

Comment: If you don't like fancy one liners, perhaps a more readable version is using `foreach`, like: `Expression body = expression;
            foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
            {
                body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
            }

            return body;`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you're trying to rewrite [Microsoft DynamicQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Why not just use that instead?

Here's an example:

```
IQueryable<Foo> myQuery = GetHibernateQuery();
myQuery = myQuery.OrderBy("address.street");
```

Comment: Because I only get an IQueryable object which contains a bunch of data already, then I add the paging and so on, afterwards I load only the data left in the query. This is done by nHibernate. Only for the sorting it cannot be the solution (I hope)

Comment: That's my point. DynamicQuery can already do this "add the sorting to an existing queryable." I have a demo solution on my blog which does just this. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/27/38243/

Comment: I added a trivial example to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    public static IQueryable<T> SortIQueryable<T>(IQueryable<T> data, string fieldName, string sortOrder)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName)) return data;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder)) return data;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");

        MemberExpression property = null;
        string[] fieldNames = fieldName.Split('.');
        foreach (string filed in fieldNames)
        {
            if (property == null)
            {
                property = Expression.Property(param, filed);
            }
            else
            {
                property = Expression.Property(property, filed);
            }
        }

        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));//Expression.Property(param, fieldName)
        var mySortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, param);

        return (sortOrder == "desc") ? data.OrderByDescending(mySortExpression)
            : data.OrderBy(mySortExpression);
    }
```