# C# Building subproperty MemberAccess LINQ expression using navigation string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda, expression

## Intro

Let's say that I have these classes:

```
public class Door {
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class House {
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Door FrontDoor { get; set; }
}
```

Now, those are simple models in the DB, abstracted using Entity Framework 4. Therefore, when I need to make an ordered list of `House` then I can use:

```
dbObjectContext.Houses.OrderBy(h=>h.Name);
```

Then, if I want to order by `FrontDoor.Label`, I can use:

```
dbObjectContext.Houses.OrderBy(h=>h.FrontDoor.Label);
```

## Problem

I intend to make a sorting method that is intended to be used by a WPF DataGrid that will display a list of Houses. The method signature is like below:

```
IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ApplySortingToQuery<TEntity>(bool ascending
    ,IQueryable<TEntity> finderQuery,string propertyPath)
```

I want to build *OrderBy* expression using the knowledge of the object type `TEntity` and the property access path string `propertyPath`.

In the DataGrid, the objects to be sorted is of type `House`, and it's columns are *Address* and *Front Door Label*. Now, the *Address* column in the DataGrid has `SortMemberPath` set to `Address`. Whereas, the *Front Door Label* column's is `FrontDoor.Label`.

In the beginning, I can just use `if-else` to determine what the *OrderBy* expression to be used, e.g.:

```
if (col.SortMemberPath=="Address") {
    query=query.OrderBy(h=>h.Address);
} else if (col.SortMemberPath=="FrontDoor.Label") {
    query=query.OrderBy(h=>h.FrontDoor.Label);
}
```

However, this functionality is very generic IMHO. So, a utility function to do it that will consult `SortMemberPath` and use it as `propertyPath` in the method is going be a great help for many other applications that will use it.

I've consulted this [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene) that help me to somewhat make this utility function, but only direct property access is successful (i.e.: `Address`), but accessing sub property (i.e.: `FrontDoor.Label`) isn't successful.

Please guide me.

Comment: see this: [`Access nested properties with dynamic lambda using Linq.Expression`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674041/access-nested-properties-with-dynamic-lambda-using-linq-expression)

Comment: or: [How do I apply OrderBy on an IQueryable using a string column name within a generic extension method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene)

Comment: Hmm... 'dynamic query' is the keywords... I'll check and test it first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is in the web all along.. (as always)

> > http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Now, I just need to compile a DLL using `CSharpSamples.zip\LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs`, making the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace available. Then, the method implementation will become very simple.

The important keywords are `dynamic query`... The right keywords for the right question sometimes are hard to come by.