# how to select multi columns filter with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

**is there a short way,
I don't want to use "if state" for every situation**
what do you think
Description :   type of query  is IQueryable

```
public class OrderFilter{
     public string SearchValue { get => _searchValue.ToLower(); set => _searchValue = value; }
     public string[] SearchColumns { get; set; }
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderFilter.SearchValue))
            
   if (orderFilter.SearchColumns.Contains("warehouse"))
       query = query.Where(x => x.Warehouse.Description.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue));
   if (orderFilter.SearchColumns.Contains("date"))
      query = query.Where(x => x.Date.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue));
   if (orderFilter.SearchColumns.Contains("warehouse") && orderFilter.SearchColumns.Contains("date"))
      query = query.Where(x => x.OrderNo.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue)
                    || x.Warehouse.Description.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue)
                    || x.Client.Description.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue)
                    || x.Date.ToString().Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue)
                    || x.Salesman.Username.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue)
                    );
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access nested properties with dynamic lambda using Linq.Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674041/access-nested-properties-with-dynamic-lambda-using-linq-expression)
found the answer I was looking for

```
public class LambdaHelper
    {
        public Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> MultiSearchOrder<TSource>(string[] columns, string value)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x"); // x=>  . ... demektir. parametre
            MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(String) });
            Expression dynamiclambda = null;
            MethodCallExpression call = null;
            foreach (var propertyName in columns)
            {

                MemberExpression propertyAccess = NestedExpressionProperty(parameter, propertyName);
                call = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(value));
                if (null == dynamiclambda)
                {
                    dynamiclambda = call;
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamiclambda = Expression.Or(dynamiclambda, call);
                }
            }
            Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(dynamiclambda, parameter);

            return predicate;

        }
 
        private MemberExpression NestedExpressionProperty(Expression expression, string propertyName)
        {
            string[] parts = propertyName.Split('.');
            int partsL = parts.Length;

            return (partsL > 1)
                ?
                Expression.Property(
                    NestedExpressionProperty(
                        expression,
                        parts.Take(partsL - 1)
                            .Aggregate((a, i) => a + "." + i)
                    ),
                    parts[partsL - 1])
                :
                Expression.Property(expression, propertyName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you add one property (SearchKey) that property contains of all properties value that used for search in writing time and you using this property instead of OR for example :

```
 savingTime: SearhKey="OrderNo.value Warehouse.Description.Value ...."

 Searching Time:
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderFilter.SearchValue))
 {
     query = query.Where(x => 
    x.SearchKey.Contains(orderFilter.SearchValue) );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do an extension o `OrderFilter` and reuse it :

```
public static bool HasAny<TSource>(this OrderFilter filter, IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if(filter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));

    if(filter.SearchColumns == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter.SearchColumns));
    
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.SearchValue))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter.SearchValue));

    if(source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    
    var properties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Where(x=> filter.SearchColumns.Any(s=> s.IndexOf(x.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0));

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(item)?.ToString();
            
            if(value?.Equals(filter.SearchValue , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    
    return false;
}
```

now you can do this :

```
var isValueExists = orderFilter.HasAny(query);
```

Comment: thank for your answer but I dont want this , I edited the question

Comment: @Cll is `orderFilter.SearchColumns`  `IEnumerable<string>` ?

Comment: public class OrderFilter{
     public string SearchValue { get => _searchValue.ToLower(); set => _searchValue = value; }
     public string[] SearchColumns { get; set; }
}

Comment: @Cll thank you, and you're looking for a way to search all columns in one set right ?

Comment: dynamic select columns with query for example    just select two column orderNo and warehouse or only orderNo  or ony date or ony salesman  I edited question you should look.

Comment: @Cll thank you, I have updated my answer, though, you could do the dynamic search on client side (using JS, pure or by using library such as jquery dataTable) which would be more efficient.

Comment: I'm sorry iSR5 because I asked the wrong question "type of query is IQueryable" so I didn't use you answser    secondly I don't use dataTable js library because orderpage has much data so  I must backend searching  if you have much data you should use backend searching